# Vector Calculation

Tags: c#, .net, vector

I would like to calculate with vectors in C# and [this Site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.vector(v=vs.110).aspx) told me to code like this:

```
Vector v = new Vector();
```

I am using:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows;
```

Anyway it does not work "Type or namespace could not be found" ...

Comment: (1) What if you use `var vector = new System.Windows.Vector();`? (2) Have you tried adding a reference to WindowsBase to your assembly? I'm guessing (2) will be it.

Comment: @WaiHaLee Yep, it was (2), thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check the documentation for `Vector`, for example google .Net `Vector`

This will give you a [MSDN page with the documentation of struct Vector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.vector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Look at this MSDN site for `namespace` this tells you that `Vector` resides in the Systems.Windows namespace.

This means you need a

```
using System.Windows;
```

line at the beginning of your code.

Furthermore the docu says that this type is in Assembly `WindowsBase.dll`.

This means you must add `WindowsBase.DLL` to the References of your project.

Comment: Oh, forgot the WindowsBas.dll... Thanks! :)